# Firebase Storing access_token Locally

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've just had an Android Firebase app penetration tested, and the tester found a file com.google.Firebase.auth.api.xml within Shared Preferences. It contained the access_token + refresh_token (which could be used to access the Firebase API).

Has anyone else experienced this vulnerability and know the best way to fix it?

(I can't work out or understand why this information is being stored locally, I've taken a look through the Firebase documentation and through my app and as far as I can tell everything is integrated properly. The app itself uses Firebase as the backend server which handles logins, authentication, Firestore and Storage)

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got in touch with Firebase and this is the response for anyone interested:

"I understand your concern, as you have said the file is used to re-authenticate the user, however, those values are set after a successful login and the SDK updates that file each hour. The vulnerabilities that you may have noticed should be related to modifying information related to that specific user and the features or data the user has access to. Please remember that the Firebase security is not only on the Authentication product, they are more tools that enforce the security in a Firebase application, that is the reason why your Security Rules should avoid insecure rules and match with your business model."